# selenium not setting input field value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Let's say we have this website https://www.coinichiwa.com/ which has a BET AMOUNT input box. It's html is:

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="betFa" name="a" maxlength="20" value="0.00000000" class="betinput" style="">
```

I need to add some value into it. Here is my code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.coinichiwa.com')

browser.find_element_by_id("betFa").send_keys("0.00000005")
print browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'betFa')]").text
```

But it's neither setting it's value to "0.00000005" nor it printing the `value` of input.

I'm not sure what's going wrong. Can you suggest?
Why it's not working?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to [`clear()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.clear) the text input first:

```
bet_fa = browser.find_element_by_id("betFa")
bet_fa.clear()
bet_fa.send_keys("0.00000005")
```

As for the your second problem - this is an `input` and the value you enter into it is kept inside the `value` attribute, not the text. Use [`get_attribute()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'betFa')]").get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: thanks, it worked like charm but one more issue... how do i get `<div style="float:left;font-size:14px;width:120px;height:25px;border-color:#ACACAC;background-color:#EAEAEA;color:black"><div style="margin:4px;" id="jukeamt">0.00100101</div></div>` the `jukeamt` <div>'s inside value?

Comment: @CracLock okay, If I understood the question correctly: `driver.find_element_by_id('jukeamt').text`.

Comment: ah, not working this way. tried but it's returning empty

Comment: @CracLock well, it is a separate problem, definitely solvable - please consider asking a separate question if you need help and throw me a link here in comments. Thank you for understanding.