# Display text in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to display text in what seems to be a container in web using selenium webdriver for python.
Here is the inspect element -

```
<div style="overflow-x: hidden;">
  <div class="view-container" style="flex-direction: row; 
  transition: all 0s ease 0s; transform: translate(0%, 0px); direction: ltr; 
  display: flex; will-change: transform;">
    <div aria-hidden="false" data-swipeable="true" style="width: 100%; flex-
    shrink: 0; overflow: auto;">
      <div>
        <div class="qs-text">What is the answer to this question?</div>
```

I want it to display "What is the answer to this question"

I'm trying to use the below, but it doesn't return anything. -

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("qs-text").text
print(element)
```

I tried `find_element_by_css_selector("qs-text").text` but that didn't help either.
Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: *"but it doesn't return anything"* Do you mean you just get an empty string or exception raised?

Comment: Maybe this other thread will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346240/selenium-not-setting-input-field-value

Comment: @Andersson - 
I get an empty string when I use find_element_by_class and the below error when I use find_element_by_css_selector - 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"qs-text"}

Comment: @Manu try `driver.find_element_by_class_name("qs-text").get_attribute('textContent')`

Comment: This  worked!
Thank you @Andersson

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'qs-text') and contains(text(), 'answer')]")

print(element)
```